# Copying array of ints vs pointers to bools

Tags: c++, arrays, optimization, boolean, int

I'm working on a program that requires an array to be copied many thousands/millions of times. Right now I have two ways of representing the data in the array:

An array of ints:

```
int someArray[8][8];
```

where `someArray[a][b]` can have a value of 0, 1, or 2, or

An array of pointers to booleans:

```
bool * someArray[8][8];
```

where `someArray[a][b]` can be 0 (null pointer), otherwise `*someArray[a][b]` can be true (corresponding to 1), or false (corresponding to 2).

Which array would be copied faster (and yes, if I made the pointers to booleans array, I would have to declare new bools every time I copy the array)?

Comment: Hang on, what?  Surely the value of `someArray[a][b]` in the second case should be a pointer, not an integer.  Are you talking about `*someArray[a][b]`?

Comment: @oli oh yes you're right, I'll update the question, thanks!

Comment: `enum boolean { false, true, FileNotFound };`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Which would copy faster is beside the point,  The overhead of allocating and freeing entries, and dereferencing the pointer to retrieve each value, for your `bool*` approach will swamp the cost of copying.

If you just have 3 possible values, use an array of `char` and that will copy 4 times faster than `int`.  OK, that's not a scientifically proven statement but the array **will** be 4 times smaller.

Comment: "4 times smaller" is not the best we can do here in terms of size - see my post ;)

Comment: @Kos - understood.  This is a pragmatic suggestion for OP's design issue, and not intended to be optimal in space usage.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, both look more or less the same in terms of copying - an array of 32-bit ints vs an array of 32-bit pointers. If you compile as 64-bit, then the pointer would probably be bigger.

BTW, if you store pointers, you probably don't want to have a SEPARATE instance of "bool" for every field of that array, do you? That would be certainly much slower.

If you want a fast copy, reduce the size as much as possible, Either:

- use `char` instead of `int`, or
- devise a **custom class** with bit manipulations for this array. If you represent one value as two bits - a "null" bit and "value-if-not-null" bit, then you'd need 128 bits = 4 ints for this whole array of 64 values. This would certainly be copied very fast! But the access to any individual bit would be a bit more complex - just a few cycles more.

---

OK, you made me curious :) I rolled up something like this:

```
struct BitArray {
public:
    static const int DIMENSION = 8;

    enum BitValue {
        BitNull = -1,
        BitTrue = 1,
        BitFalse = 0
    };
    BitArray() {for (int i=0; i<DIMENSION; ++i) data[i] = 0;}
    BitValue get(int x, int y) {
        int k = x+y*DIMENSION; // [0 .. 64)
        int n = k/16;          // [0 .. 4)
        unsigned bit1 = 1 << ((k%16)*2);
        unsigned bit2 = 1 << ((k%16)*2+1);

        int isnull = data[n] & bit1;
        int value = data[n] & bit2;
        return static_cast<BitValue>( (!!isnull)*-1 + (!isnull)*!!value );
    }
    void set(int x, int y, BitValue value) {
        int k = x+y*DIMENSION; // [0 .. 64)
        int n = k/16;          // [0 .. 4)
        unsigned bit1 = 1 << ((k%16)*2);
        unsigned bit2 = 1 << ((k%16)*2+1);
        char v = static_cast<char>(value);

        // set nullbit to 1 if v== -1, else 0
        if (v == -1) {
            data[n] |= bit1;
        } else {
            data[n] &= ~bit1;
        }

        // set valuebit to 1 if v== 1, else 0
        if (v == 1) {
            data[n] |= bit2;
        } else {
            data[n] &= ~bit2;
        }
    }
private:
    unsigned data[DIMENSION*DIMENSION/16];
};
```

**The size of this object for an 8x8 array is 16 bytes**, which is a nice improvement compared to 64 bytes with the solution of `char array[8][8]` and 256 bytes of `int array[8][8]`.

This is probably as low as one can go here without delving into greater magic.

Comment: About "greater magic"- there's still the fact that this tree-state boolean carries, theoretically speaking, less than 2 bits of information. I doubt that this fact can be actually useful (13 or 14 bytes instead of 16 wouldn't help the machine), but would it be possible to really implement it in less than 16 bytes, just for the fun of doing it? Any bit-fu guru around? :)

Answer (score 1):

I would say you need to redesign your program. Converting between `int x[8][8]` and `bool *b[8][8]` "millions" of times cannot be "right" however your definition of "right" is lax.

Comment: I don't have to convert between the two, just need to copy whichever implementation of the array I choose

Comment: Ah, sorry, I've read the question too quickly :/ Dynamic memory allocation is slow. Copying int[8][8] is definitely faster.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question will be linked to the size of the data types. Typically `bool` is one byte while `int` is not. A pointer varies in length depending on the architecture, but these days is usually 32- or 64-bits.

Not taking caching or other processor-specific optimizations into consideration, the data type that is larger will take longer to copy.

Given that you have three possible states (0, 1, 2) and 64 entries you can represent your entire structure in 128 bits. Using some utility routines and two unsigned 64-bit integers you can efficiently copy your array around very quickly.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure, but I think they will take roughly the same time, though I prefer using stack allocation (since dynamic allocation might take some time looking for a free space).

Consider using `short` type instead of `int` since you do not need a wide range of numbers.

I think it might be better to use one dimension array if you really want maximum speed since using the `for` loops in the wrong order which the compiler use for storing multidimensional arrays (raw major or column major) could cause performance penalty!

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing too much about how you use the arrays, this is a possible solution:

```
typedef char Array[8][8];
Array someArray, otherArray;
memcpy(someArray, otherArray, sizeof(Array));
```

These arrays are only 64 bytes and should copy fairly fast. You can change the data type to `int` but that means copying at least 256 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

"copying" this array with the pointers would require a deep copy, since otherwise changing the copy will affect the original, which is probably not what you want. This is going to slow things down immensely due to the memory allocation overhead.

You can get around this by using `boost::optional` to represent "optional" quantities - which is the only reason you're adding the level of indirection here. There are very few situations in modern C++ where a raw pointer is really the best thing to be using :) However, since you only need a `char` to store the values {0, 1, 2} anyway, that will probably be better in terms of space. I am pretty sure that `sizeof(boost::optional<bool>) > 1`, though I haven't tested it. I would be impressed if they specialized for this :)

You could even bit-pack an array of 2-bit quantities, or use two bit-packed boolean arrays (one "mask" and then another set of actual true-false values) - using `std::bitset` for example. That will certainly save space and reduce copying time, although it would probably increase access time (assuming you really do need to access one value at a time).