# Data structure for storing very large 2D data in C++

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, vector, large-data

I need to handle a data table (2D) of a maximum of 100 million rows and 30 columns. The table elements contain only 0s, 1s and dashes (-). The table is given to me in a text file. I have to store this data into some data structure and perform operations like sorting the table, deleting rows, comparing elements (both in different rows and columns), etc.

Currently I am using a 2D vector for this. I tried using an integer vector and a bit vector. Both work for 10mil rows and 25 columns but neither works for the above said maximum limit (I have a bad alloc).

I am assuming that this is because the vector needs contiguous memory. What would be the right data structure for this? Timing is also one of my considerations and would want a low access time as well. Also, if a vector is actually the right data structure, is there a better implementation I could use to make this work? I have to stick to C++ and can't use databases and stuff.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: if you can devise a scheme to pack your tribool into 2 bits of storage, you would need about 2.25GB for storage.  If you gonna use a whole byte for your tribool, you'd need about 9GB.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out **Nstate**.

It is a library for Packed Arrays for an arbitrary radix (so tristates qualify).

http://nstate.hostilefork.com

Disclaimer: I wrote nstate.

Comment: @TanmayPatil Thanks for pointing out the clarification, but it's not just for tristates, you pick the radix and it does the math.  Hence "N" state.  packs 4 4-states per byte, that kind of thing.  Also my website generator markdown has a bug, aaaargh.  Fixing it.

Comment: Sure thing. I just wanted to avoid this helpful answer to be link only.

Answer (score 4):

You can consider an array of `boost::tribool`

See

- http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/tribool.html
- [Optimize an array of tribools for space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4416744/optimize-an-array-of-tribools-for-space)

You can also consider a wrapper over `std::bitset` such that for every tribool there are 2 bits in bitset.

`tribool` of size `N` requires `bitset` of size `2*N`

Mapping:

```
tribool(i) maps to bitset(2*i) and bitset(2*i+1)

if tribool(i) == indeterminate, then bitset(2*i) = false
if tribool(i) == true, then bitset(2*i) = true, bitset(2*i) = true
if tribool(i) == false, then bitset(2*i) = true, bitset(2*i) = false
```

C++ish pseudo-code:

```
template<size_t N>
class PackedTribool {
public:
  ??? test( i ) {
    if( bits_[ 2 * i ] == false ) {
        return indeterminate;
    }
    else {
        return( bits_[ 2 * i + i ];
    }
  }
private:
  std::bitset<2*N> bits_;     // note: size is doubled
};
```